# xp_instance_regread procedure is keep getting executed automatically

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using **sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats** view to see most expensive stored procedures in our database. Every time, **xp_instance_regread** is on top of the resutl table with too many execution count.

This is the query to see **xp_instance_regread** statistics;

```
select 
OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) as SP,
cached_time,
last_execution_time,
execution_count,

total_worker_time,
total_worker_time / execution_count as avg_execution_time,

total_elapsed_time,
total_elapsed_time / execution_count as avg_elapsed_time

from sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats
where OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'xp_instance_regread'
```

This is the query result;

[image]

I never used this procedure in the system, actually I learned that this procedure exists by **sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats**. It is executed like 15 times per minute. Is it possible to find cause of these executions?

Comment: Run SQL Profiler against your database and you can see every query that is executed and tonnes of details about it.

Comment: @DavidG I just run the profiler, but it isn't catching anything related to that procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal `xp_instance_regread` system procedure is used by SQL Server tools like SSMS in order to get configured values. You can verify this with a trace and then establish a new SSMS Object Explorer connection.

Comment: So i can assume that this is a normal situation and nothing has to be done about it, right?

Comment: @Mustafauçar, yes. I suspect there isn't much activity other on your SQL instance if the proc shows as one of the more expensive ones.